# Цикл foreach в html коде

Tags: php, html

Напомните плз, как вставить цикл foreach в html
Там как,то так,

```
 <?foreach($mes as $messages)?>
 <p><?=$name?></p>
 <?endforeach?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php foreach ($row as $value): ?>
    <p><?php echo $value; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```